# MYSQL count respondent and total participant

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables and I want to count the respondent and total participant

participant

```
  ID  | Name
  -------------
  1     David
  2     John
  3     Mark
  4     Jake
```

Respondent

```
  ID  | event_id | participant_id
  -------------------------------
  1       1           1
  2       1           2
  3       2           3  
  4       2           1
  5       2           2
```

the result would be like this

Report

```
  ID  | event_id | total_respondent |  number_of_participant
  -------------------------------------------------------
  1       1           2                     4
  2       2           3                     4
```

my query is this..

```
    SELECT Respondent.event_id, COUNT( Respondent.participant_id) as total_respondent 
FROM  `Respondent`
INNER JOIN participant ON Respondent.participant_id= participant.id
GROUP BY Respondent.event_id
```

I would like to include the number_of_participant in my query.. how would the query should be like.

Comment: And what did you try, which didn't work out?

Comment: How will the participant count be 6 in total, there are only 5 records

Comment: Unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please, clarify.

Comment: if I have 5 records on participant.. it would also include it on the report query

Comment: Now you have updated participant count as 4 each can you explain why, do you want it to be total of participants table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query would help if you want total participant count for both events

```
SELECT event_id, 
       COUNT(participant_id)  AS total_resondents, 
       (SELECT Count(*) 
        FROM   participants) AS participants
FROM   respondents 
GROUP  BY event_id
```

SQL Fiddle example http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1334e/4/0